# How to create default date set on a calendar in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, vertica

I have one vertica query in my tableau,

```
select * from mytable where Date(sometimestamp) between 
start_date and end_date
```

As you can see data varies as per change in date range.

My issue is to set start_date as default to current_date - 90 and end_date as current_date.

There is not issue in making end_date as current_date but no idea about how to set start_date as current_date-90 in tableau.

I tried making calculated fields etc but none helps.

Could you please guide me on how to do that.

Note - Both, start_date and end_date should be calendar component not dropdowns or slider.

Comment: Can you do a tableu side expression? `DATEADD('day', -90, NOW() )`

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that!!! I am new to Tableau.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding a filter to your data source -- note that you won't be able to control this filter from the dashboard (if that's what you want to do, you'll need to create a calculated field and let the users interact with it), rather, this is a datasource level filter.

Go to the data source and click "Add" under the filters text in the top right, then click "Add"
Click the "Relative dates" [image]
Then, select Relative Dates, Months, Last 3 (Or select Days and enter 90 under the "Last" radio button) and press OK.

You said you have the end date handled, but you can create another data source filter to handle the end date if you want.

Comment: Actually, fetching last 90 days data is not my issue. My issue is showing two calendars on dashboards. One with Today's date and other one with Todays Date-90.

Comment: Like Woot said in their comment, you can create a calculated field: Click Analysis menu (at the top) and select Create Calculated Field, then enter the code that Woot provided.